# Is SQLite DataSource compatible with Crystal Reports?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sqlite, crystal-reports

I am thinking to use SQLite for the newer version of my app. Is SQLite compatible with Crystal Reports? I am using VS2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge Crystal Reports supports ADO.NET data providers wihch [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) uses so yes, it should be compatible.